# yaml file handlers configuration

Tags: yaml, app.yaml

I have an app.yaml file with this handelrs configuration:

```
handlers:
  # Serve all static files with url ending with a file extension
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$
  # Catch all handler to index.html
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
```

My issue is that when I have an email address in the url, It tries to get it as a static file, which causes an 404 error.
For example - **mydomain.com/john.doe@gmail.com**
This should be a regular route, not a static file. It's because of the dot in the emails.
How can I configure the yaml differently to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to come up with proper definition of what paths identify static files. Your current definition is broken because it matches mail addresses, which you do not want. This is not a YAML or RegEx problem, it is a specification problem.

A possible solution would be to say „if there's an `@` symbol in the path, it is never a static file“. That would be rather easy to implement:

```yaml
  - url: /([^@]*\.[^@]+)$
```

A different solution would be to filter for known file extensions:

```yaml
  - url: /(.*\.(html|css|js|jpeg|gif|png))$
```

(add whatever extensions are relevant for you)

Comment: Thank you! We have too many extrnsions to pull the second option off. Regarding the first one- it still maches email addresses - blabla@mail.com for example. Any suggestions?

Comment: @liansk It doesn't match email addresses according to the POSIX extended regex standard, which app.yaml claims to use. `[^@]` does match every character but `@` and there is no Regex standard I know where this isn't the case, so I don't see how this can still match email addresses. Check if you really deployed this properly before testing.

Comment: flyx you are correct. I've only tested the regex in an online regex tester. Once I deployed the app with your solution in WORKED! Thanks a lot!!